# Deletion using sqlalchemy takes 45 mins, how to increase speed

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert a SQL statement given below:

```sql
DELETE FROM  traceability.autodiscovery WHERE (sapsystemname) in (SELECT DISTINCT sapsystemname FROM traceability.lastrun_workorders)
```

to this using sqlalchemy:

```py
autodiscovery.delete().where(autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname in df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist())
```

The problem is that if I execute this:

```py
print(autodiscovery.delete().where(autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname in df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist()))
```

I'm getting this output:

```sql
DELETE FROM autodiscovery WHERE false
```

Figured out what was needed to do, I had to iterate through the list to get what i needed.

```
for i in df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist():
    print(autodiscovery.delete().where(autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname == i))
```

This gave the output,

```
DELETE FROM  traceability.autodiscovery WHERE sapsystemname is :sapsystemname_1
```

where `:sapsystemname_1` is nothing but `i`.

Now that gives rise to another question,

This way of deleting involves a loop which will be slow when the size of `df` is very huge. Normally I have to deal with datasets with 200k - 600k rows.
The db table itself has 1 - 1.5 million records out of which I have to delete 200k - 600k rows.

With the first code snippet, it takes around 45 to 50 mins to perform the delete.

What method would possibly be efficient to go with in that case?
Please suggest any faster alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the `where` method is incorrectly constructed.

```py
autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname in df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist()
```

is a standard membership test, testing whether the column object `autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname` is present in the list generated by `df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist()`. It isn't, so the argument evaluates to `False` immediately.

To create an `IN` clause you need to pass the list of values to the column's [in_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.in_) method:

```py
autodiscovery.delete().where(autodiscovery.c.sapsystemname.in_(df['sapsystemname'].unique().tolist()))
```